# React front end not updating after delete operation in MERN application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have a MERN application where I'm trying to delete a note (consisting of a title and content) when the delete button is clicked. When I click the button, the backend mongoDB database is updated - the item is, in fact, deleted - but then the console spits out an error.

Here's the delete operation, traced through the relevant files:

```
// App.jsx

const deleteNote = id => {
    NoteDataService.deleteNote(id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(`note ${id} deleted`);
        setNotes(prevState => {
          return prevState.notes.filter(note => note._id !== id);
        });
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };


// note.js

import http from '../http-common.js';

class NoteDataService {
  createNote = data => http.post('/', data);

  getAll = () => http.get('/');

  deleteNote = id => http.delete(`?id=${id}`);
}

export default new NoteDataService();


// http-common.js

import http from '../http-common.js';

class NoteDataService {
  createNote = data => http.post('/', data);

  getAll = () => http.get('/');

  deleteNote = id => http.delete(`?id=${id}`);
}

export default new NoteDataService();
```

And here's the error:

```
App.jsx:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at App.jsx:41
```

Of the CRUD operations I'm attempting to implement, it seems only the "Read" (get) functionality is working properly to initially populate my list of notes from the backend (using useEffect() on App component load).

Answer (score 0):

This works...

```
  const deleteNote = id => {
    NoteDataService.deleteNote(id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(`note ${id} deleted`);
        console.log(notes);
        setNotes(notes.filter(note => note._id !== id));
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the component mount your state `notes` will be `null`. Do check `notes` in your state is not `null` and it's an `array` will be fine

`prevState.notes && prevState.notes.filter(note => note._id !== id)`

Comment: Thanks - I tried your suggestion as well, but that also gave me an error. The answer I gave (avoiding any reference to prevState) is the only thing that works.